# jQuery prepend unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, prepend

I want to prepend a div dynamically to another div using jQuery append function, but am getting some error.Here is my code:

```
prepend_data ='<div class="media">
<a class="pull-left" href="#">
<img class="media-object img-circle" src="<?=base_url()?  >folder/holderjs/holder.js/64x64">
<div class="media-body">
<h4 class="media-heading">
<strong>'+item.name+'</strong><span class="text-green">good</span> mode
</h4>
<abbr title="title">Location:</abbr>some text<br>
<abbr title="Phone">Ph:</abbr>'+' '+item.phone+'</div>
</div>';

$('.container').prepend(prepend_data);
```

Am getting this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier "

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: your string concatenation does not seems to be proper... you have new line characters without proper string literal endings

Comment: try `prepend_data ='<div class="media">' +
'<a class="pull-left" href="#">' +
'<img class="media-object img-circle" src="<?=base_url()?  >folder/holderjs/holder.js/64x64">' +
'<div class="media-body">' +
'<h4 class="media-heading">' +
'<strong>'+item.name+'</strong><span class="text-green">good</span> mode' +
'</h4>' +
'<abbr title="title">Location:</abbr>some text<br>' +
'<abbr title="Phone">Ph:</abbr>'+' '+item.phone+'</div>' +
'</div>';`

Comment: I have tried this but not working for me..Suppose i need to add this prepend data div to another div like <div class="tab-pane" id="alerts"><div class="log-box"> this then how would i code and adding part of code in jquery..i have given something like $('.log-box').prepend(prepend_data); but it is not working for me..

Answer (score 0):

Remove all line breaks, so all the 'div's' content  will be in the same line